# Looking for a solution to synchronize data between Postgres database running in AWS Aurora DB (pgsync maybe?)

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, amazon-aurora

We are trying to find a solution to synchronize the data from one database (let's call it **Master**) database to another database (let's call it **Analytics**)  to perform ETL operations in **Analytics**.

The setup would be as follows:

- Tables from **Master** would be replicated in **Analytics**
- Replicated tables in **Analytics** would be read-only in analytics but used in certain ETL scripts (some of them purely SQL) to perform some insertions in other tables in **Analytics**

From our initial research it seems [PGSync](https://github.com/ankane/pgsync) would be a good solution to perform this. We have been trying AWS DMS as well but it created too much of a drag on resources on **Master**.

Has anyone attempted a similar setup in the past? Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using DB links as I have used once to for analytics between Postgres to redshift so it will be feasible to use it between Postgres to Postgres

the example between Postgres to redshift.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/join-amazon-redshift-and-amazon-rds-postgresql-with-dblink/

Comment: Thanks this is the route we went with, works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

You can create read_replicas in AWS RDS [here is some additional info](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/rds/details/read-replicas/).
I think this is what you are searching for - note that for aurora Read replicas can also become master in case of a failure.

Comment: Hi @FransDel , we wish to sync the data to another DB that will allow read-write operations. The data from the tables that are synced would be kept read-only but we'd insert data in other tables in that same database.

Comment: Okay then you could use AWS Batch or DataPipline to do such a job. Does the sync need to be real-time?